# mysql - copy IDs from one table to another for first n rows

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have 2 tables:

table1:

```
shareID |    shareName
__________________

1         shareA
2         shareB
3         shareC
```

table2:

```
shareID |    shareName
__________________

0         shareA
0         shareA
0         shareB
0         shareC
```

I need to copy the shareID from table1 to table2 for the matching shareName.

I have this query which works

```
UPDATE table1, table2 SET table2.shareID=table1.shareID WHERE table2.shareName=table1.shareName
```

But the problem is that table2 has ~600K rows, and table1 about 350. So with the query about this takes too long.

Originally I thought it wouldn't work due to memory constraints, but as I was writing this question, the query completed and I have what I need. Took about 5 mins maybe more. But I'd like to know if there is a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `table2.table1`? `WHERE and`? Please post the correct query.

Comment: Tables are unordered.  You must use `ORDER BY` to specify which rows are the "first N".

Comment: `... WHERE and ...` -- please fix your syntax error.  While you are at it, change to `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- you may be missing some important indexes.

Comment: Modifying 600K rows takes a long time.  There is the undo log, etc that must be written.

Comment: Very sorry, fixed the errors now.

Comment: You're never going to need to do it again, so why worry?

Comment: I need to do it when new records are added, which is about 350/day. Since the source of it has only names (ids are created by me), I have to assign IDs to these new rows. Plus I wanna know just for the sake finding a better approach is there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a `join`:

```
UPDATE table1 t1 JOIN
       table2 t2
       ON t2.shareName = t1.shareName
    SET t2.shareId = t1.shareID ;
```

Then, add an index:

```
create index idx_table1_shareName on table1(shareName);
```

Actually, I'm not sure which table is better for the index (I'm confused by the fact that the table names in your query differ from the names in the question).  So, build one on both tables:

```
create index idx_table2_shareName on table2(shareName);
```

Comment: I fixed the table names. I changed it for simplicity in the question but messed up when C/Ping

Comment: For a small set of 191 rows in table2, my query is marginally faster by 0.003 secs. I will try it on a bigger set an update with results. I did not add the index though.

Comment: @fractal5 . . . The key part of the answer is the index.